# Firebase Admin : getUser isn't working while verifyIdToken works

Tags: node.js, firebase-authentication, firebase-admin, google-cloud-identity

I'm initializing the firebase config as following,

```
firebaseAdmin.initializeApp({
  credential: applicationDefault(),
  projectId: "${my_project_id}",
});
```

Verify ID token is working,

```
firebaseAdmin
    .app()
    .auth()
    .verifyIdToken(idToken)
    .then((decodedIDToken) => {
      console.log("decodedIDToken: ", decodedIDToken);
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log("error: ", error);
    })
```

But getUser is throwing error,

```
firebaseAdmin
      .app()
      .auth()
      .getUser(uuid)
      .then((data) => {
        console.log("user: ", data);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log("error: ", error);
      });
```

Error

```
errorInfo: {
    code: 'auth/internal-error',
    message: '//cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/adc-troubleshooting/user-creds . Raw server response: "{"error":{"code":403,"message":"Your application is authenticating by using local Application Default Credentials. The identitytoolkit.googleapis.com API requires a quota project, which is not set by default. To learn how to set your quota project, see https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/adc-troubleshooting/user-creds .","errors":[{"message":"Your application is authenticating by using local Application Default Credentials. The identitytoolkit.googleapis.com API requires a quota project, which is not set by default. To learn how to set your quota project, see https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/adc-troubleshooting/user-creds .","domain":"usageLimits","reason":"accessNotConfigured","extendedHelp":"https://console.developers.google.com"}],"status":"PERMISSION_DENIED","details":[{"@type":"type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.ErrorInfo","reason":"SERVICE_DISABLED","domain":"googleapis.com","metadata":{"service":"identitytoolkit.googleapis.com","consumer":"projects/${some_project_ID"}}]}}"'
  },
  codePrefix: 'auth'
}
```

I've ensured to set the correct project to both application-default and default project by running these,

```
$ gcloud auth application-default set-quota-project ${some_different project}
$ gcloud config set project ${my_project_id}
```

I've also confirmed both the projects have Identity Toolkit API enabled.
[image]

Comment: I was able to unblock myself changing app authentication to use a service key instead of application default credentials. While this works, this is hardly an ideal solution.