auth/internal-error | Your application is authenticating by using local Application Default Credentials
During development, I am currently only setting GOOGLE_CLOUD_PROJECT=project-dev with my personal account user@gmail.com logged in with gcloud. user@gmail.com is also allowed to impersonate project-backend-sa@gmail.com.
This is, if I understood this configuration correctly, the reason why I am able to, for example, upload images from the (local) web client to my (local) server and upload it to one of my configured Google Cloud Storage (GCS) buckets.
However, the backend server also allows administrators to grant certain roles to users.
const firebaseUser = await admin.auth().getUser(user.firebaseUid);
const roles = (firebaseUser.customClaims?.roles ?? []) as string[];

// Add user-admin role
const claims = new Set<string>([...roles, 'user-admin']);

await admin.auth().setCustomUserClaims(user.firebaseUid, { roles: [...claims] });

The problem here is, however, already calling
admin.auth().getUser(user.firebaseUid)

Which throws the auth/internal-error stating:

Your application is authenticating by using local Application Default Credentials. The identitytoolkit.googleapis.com API requires a quota project, which is not set by default.

{
  "@type":"type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.ErrorInfo",
  "reason":"SERVICE_DISABLED",
  "domain":"googleapis.com",
  "metadata": { 
    "service": "identitytoolkit.googleapis.com",
    "consumer":"projects/123456789012"
  }
}

However, the identitytoolkit.googleapis.com service is definitely enabled on the GCP project project-dev.

What I also not understand is why I am able to upload to GCS or why I can still use firebase-admin to verify tokens:
admin.auth()
  .verifyIdToken(token)
  .then(/* .. */);

I already checked .config/gcloud/application_default_credentials.json. It does seem to contain the correct client_id and quota_project_id is set to project-dev. Only "account" appears to be empty.
One thing to note: projects/123456789012 or 123456789012 is not an existing project number of mine. That's the only odd thing I can point to but I'm not sure if that's the problem here. I Re-authenticated multiple times and set the default to project-dev.

Are you 100% sure project-dev is your project ID and not your project name? menu > cloud overview > dashboard

@danyL I am.. the project name is "Project Development", the ID is project-dev  and the number is 9876543210 and not 123456789012.

not entirely sure perhaps look into https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/auth/application-default/set-quota-project

Lastly, Fallen mentions about using service key instead of ADC https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76879438/firebase-admin-getuser-isnt-working-while-verifyidtoken-works

@danyL thank you. I did already try to explicitly set the default quota project without success. Looks like user Fallen has the exact problem like me. I have switched to using a key myself in the meantime. Could this be a bug on Google's side?

Would be interesting if @Fallen ever found a solution.
